# find the smallest period in list of dates

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime

is there a way an idea to find the smallest period in list of dates:

```
A: startDate|----------------------|EndDate
B: startDate|------------|EndDate
C: startDate|-----------------|EndDate
```

the smallest period is in this exemple is B.
I need an idea to begin

Comment: Sure there ist. What have you tried? One solution would be to calculate the difference in total days and sort on the result.

Comment: [DateTime.Subtract(Datetime)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=net-6.0) gives you [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0) you can sort and pick the shortest.

Comment: Why is `C` the shortest, `B` looks shorter to me?

Comment: @Charlieface is was just a mistake, thanks for ur comment I'm gonna correct it

Comment: Are you really asking how to find the smallest among a set of numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the difference in time to get a sequence of timeSpans, and pick the smallest one. For example using LINQ

```
var shortestPeriod = myDates.Min(d => d.startDate - s.EndDate);
```

If you want the actual start and end dates for the shortest interval you could use [MinBy](https://morelinq.github.io/3.1/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_Extensions_MinByExtension_MinBy__2.htm), for .Net versions older than 6 it is available in the MoreLinq library, or you could just write your own.

Comment: Just a note, with `.NET 6`, you can use [`Enumerable.MinBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.minby?view=net-6.0) as well.